# Change the Folders list that Windows 8.1 Shows when File Explorer is Launched

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer

I launch File Explorer on Windows 8.1 by pressing the Win+E shortcut.

When File Explorer opens it shows a right panel called "Folders" (circled in Red in my screenshot)

[image]

I'd like this pane to show my Explorer Favorites instead (those things displayed under the Favorites tree node in the left pane. How can I change this "Folders" view?

Comment: if you want to change the location of that folder?

Comment: see this link, you will get some idea http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18629-user-folders-change-default-location.html

Comment: @shankar I'm sorry but the sevenforums link is also not what I want. I do not want to change the location of my Music or Downloads folder. When I launch Explorer with Win+E, the right pane shows 6 items (circled in red). How can I add c:\Workspace\projects as a 7th item? How can I hide Desktop as an item?

Comment: see that link clearly, the forum tells that how to create a new folder and add to launch explorer.

Comment: In that forum, he doesn't used the default Music folder.  He created a new folder named as My music and replaced it. Try to follow that forum..

Comment: @shankar I followed the directions and this is definitely not what I need. Their step 6 is: 
"Right click or press and hold on a user folder (ex: My Music, My Documents, My Pictures, etc.....) that you want to move the default location for..." I do not want to move the default location for any of my 6 libraries. I want to add a 7th.

Comment: @and31415 yes, it is a duplicate of your link